# Change the text according to match for each line

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a text file which contains some text is shown below:

```
I love bash
$ I love html
$ I hate you
I love you man
```

I want to add some text at the beginning and the end of the line with a match of `$`. Means all the line which contains `$` sign should have some text at the beginning "`yes`" and the end "`man`".

Output required:

```
I love bash
Yes I love html man
Yes I hate you man
I love you man
```

Comment: Trap: a naked dollar sign denotes "end of line" for sed, so you have to prefix it with a backslash.

Comment: I have really bad experiences with awk. nawk, gnu awk, too many brands with the same name, all behaving differently. If you can do with one-liners in shell, do it. If you need more, use perl or java.

Comment: loving `bash`, `awk` or `sed` or any other tool is not enough to resolve your problem in your real life, you will need to **"learn how to use them"** first then you will love them too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *replace* the leading `$` (as per your original question) then the KISS approach is

```
sed '/^\$/{s/^\$/Yes/;s/$/ man/}' file
```

This can be abbreviated to

```
sed '/^\$/{s//Yes/;s/$/ man/}' file
```

by making use of the fact that `//` matches the previous regex.

A more sophisticated solution, making use of branching with the GNU sed `T` extension:

```
sed 's/^\$/Yes/;T;s/$/ man/' file
```

With non-GNU sed you would need to invert the branch logic:

```
sed 's/^\$/Yes/;ta;b;:a;s/$/ man/' file
```

If you want to *preserve* the leading `$` (as per comments) then

```
sed '/^\$/{s/^/Yes /;s/$/ man/}' file
```